# Why do I get this error when uploading a sketch on my arduino uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, upload

I have two Arduino Unos. On the first I can upload my sketch wittout any error, but with my second Arduino I always get this error, altough Im using the same settings:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xbf
```

What I tried:

- different Usb Port
- different Usb Cable
- swapped the MCU on the board
- restarted VSCODE

Comment: I also have this error sometimes, especially when I'm switching boards or usb port and forget to reselect  the device at Tools > Port.